# Spring Batch Update: Insert only if does not exist otherwise update

Tags: sql-server, spring

I need to write a batch update statement. I am able to do that. I dont have any primary key in my table. There are chances that duplicate data will be sent to database. 
I want to write batch update in such a manner that It will insert only if data does not exist. When I say data does not exist, I mean 3 columns of the table which can uniquely identify a row. I don't want to make a primary key using these 3 columns.
Is there a way where we can write batch update which will insert only if data does not exist otherwise it will do the update. 
I have tried merge query but could not get it. 
Thanks

Comment: Yes, Merge is the right way. Could you provide an example query that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ItemProcessor to [filter out](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#filiteringRecords) duplicated items with a query, just return null if item is already present in database: objects that pass the processor can be written with ItemWriter and you are sure there are not duplicated